# Google Script - Emailed Chart Changes Date Format

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

When I create a chart in google script, its lists all of the horizontal axis labels.

[image]

I email the chart using the script:

```
var chartBlobs=new Array(pageCharts.length); 
var imageInsertsHtml = "<h2>Short summary</h2>";
var emailImages={};
for(var i=0;i<pageCharts.length;i++){
   chartBlobs[i]=pageCharts[i].getBlob().getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob"+i);
   imageInsertsHtml= imageInsertsHtml + "<img src='cid:chart"+i+"'><br>";
   emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
}
```

Then the chart is sent out like this:
[image]

The points are still there but the horizontal axis is condensed.

Ive tried converting my cells to plain text using .setNumberFormat but i get an error since the dates are its own object.

Any help would be great!

Comment: If you forgo the double conversion `getBlob().getAs` and instead just `getAs`, does this persist?

Comment: I changed the line to chartBlobs[i]= pageCharts[i].getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob"+i);

and got the same result

Comment: Note that more than just the date format has changed - all of your chart axes options have essentially reset. Has your research turned up any SO questions, Apps Script Issue Tracker posts, or internet search results related to axis options in exported Google Sheets charts?

Comment: Oh i didnt even notice the y axis changed as well. No where in the code do we change the graph axis before emailing it. Ill have to look into if emailing changes graph axis. Ill report back with a fix or info.

Comment: So it looks like my axis's are continuous axis and, unless i manually specify them, i will always get the condensed axis's. 
One thing im going to try is to make it into a discrete axis to take advantage of hAxis.showTextEvery

Comment: I think whats happening is when i create the dates in pandas, they get converted to the date object in google. That sets the axis to continuous since the values are not strings. I think i would have to go back and change it so that data type remains as a string when google loads it into a sheet.